# Creating a list of permutations (without replacement) for 1 to 16 sequence

Tags: r, bigdata, permutation, combinatorics

I need to iterate over a list of all possible permutations of a 1 to 16 sequence.
I tried `permn(1:16)` from the `combinat` package, but the vector is too large - I get an error that says:

```
Error: cannot allocate vector of size 155886.9 Gb
```

Is there a way of getting around this? I thought of maybe splitting the permutations generation somehow...but hasn't come up with a proper answer.

Comment: How big is your vector?

Comment: Well, 16! (as in 16 factorial) is ~2.1e13, so that's how many permutations you are creating. That's quite a large vector, are you *sure* you need every permutation?

Comment: @mathematical.coffee I think I do...I need to simulate drawing the numbers one by one in every possible order.

Answer (score 1):

You could split up the operation in two, grabbing a list of all possible k-tuples for the first k elements and then iteratively grabbing all possible permutations of the remaining 16-k values. With k=6, you have:

```
vals <- 1:16
k <- 6
start <- as.matrix(do.call(expand.grid, replicate(k, vals, simplify=F)))
reps <- apply(combn(k, 2), 2, function(x) start[,x[1]] == start[,x[2]])
start <- start[rowSums(reps) == 0,]
```

Now that we have the 5.77 million valid 6-tuples that could start your combinations, "all" that remains is computing all possible permutations of the remaining 10 elements:

```
library(combinat)
apply(start, 1, function(x)) {
  remaining <- permn(vals[!vals %in% x])
  tuples <- lapply(remaining, function(y) unname(c(x, y)))
  # Process this subset of the tuples however you want
}
```

This takes about a minute for each iteration, so you are going to be pretty patient (11 years) for the full loop to run, or you would need to parallelize pretty aggressively. That being said, it could run, since your machine should no longer run out of memory at each loop iteration (you are only generating about 400 MB of permutations at a time).